# Applying posts_clauses filter to specific queries only

Tags: wp-query, filters, pre-get-posts

I've written a plugin where I need to use the `posts_clauses` filter on `WP_Query` in order to do my own JOINs and write some complex WHERE conditions that WordPress is unable to generate using the `WP_Query` API.

I need to use an anonymous function in order to close over a local variable in my callback, e.g.:

```
 add_filter('posts_clauses', function ($pieces) use ($date) {
     // generate WHERE conditions that use $date
 }
```

However, I need this filter to only be applied when querying a certain custom post type (CPT) and not on all queries.

With `pre_get_posts`, I would simply check `$query->query_vars['post_type']` and modify the query only if it matches my CPT.

Using an `call_user_func` signature instead of an anonymous function, I could simply `remove_filter` after the modification has run.

But neither of those two possibilities works in my case.

Now, I have seen ways to use `remove_filter` even when using anonymous functions, but I reckon those solutions do not look any cleaner that my current solution, which is to use `strstr` on `$pieces['where']`:

```
 if (!strstr($pieces['where'], "AND wp_posts.post_type = 'my-cpt'")) {
     return $pieces;
 }
```

Does anyone have a better idea or a cleaner solution to this?

Comment: Never add anonymous functions to action and filter hooks. Without a function name it becomes impossible for other code to remove them.

Comment: How would I then close over the $date variable that I need within my callback?

Comment: Any reason it can't just pass as a function parameter?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something or having the dumb, but I don't see how I would be able to pass a parameter into the callback function when using [apply_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/). When WordPress runs apply_filter() on 'posts_clauses', it passes an array of query pieces into the callback, but I don't see how to influence these parameters unless I closed over a variable or used currying. (cf. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/plugin.php#L199)
Could you give an example of how to pass it as a function parameter?

Comment: No. I'm the one being stupid, sorry.